# Panda3D and Python, render only one frame and other questions

Tags: python, 3d, rendering, panda3d

I would like to use Panda3D for my personal project, but after reading the documentation and some example sourcecodes, I still have a few questions:

- How can I render just one frame and save it in a file? 
  In fact I would need to render 2 different images: a single object, and a scene of multiple objects including the previous single object, but just one frame for each and they both need to be saved as image files.
- The application will be coded in Python, and needs to be very scalable (be used by thousand of users). Would Panda3D fit the bill here? (about my program in Python, it's almost a constant complexity so no problem here, and 3D models will be low-poly and about 5 to 20 per scene).
- I need to calculate the perspective projection of every object to the camera. Is it possible to directly access the vertexes and faces (position, parameters, etc..)?
- Can I recolor my 3D objects? I need to set a simple color for the whole object, but a different color per object. Is it possible?

Please also note that I'm quite a newbie in the field of graphical and game development, but I know some bits of 3D modelling and 3D theory, as well as computer imaging theory.

Thank you for reading me.

PS: My main alternative currently is to use Soya3D or PySoy, but they don't seem to be very actively developped nor optimized, so although they would both have a smaller memory footprints, I don't know if they would really perform faster than Panda3D since they're not very optimized...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can take a screenshot of your scene using `self.win.saveScreenshot(Filename)`. Example:

  ```
  from panda3d.core import Filename

  file_name = Filename('whatever.png')) 
  self.win.saveScreenshot(file_name)
  ```
- I have never used the Panda3D Networking API myself but it is supposed to do a good job on the client side. Performance on the server side with thousand of users may not be as good, but you can code the server software using other more suitable technologies for heavy networking like C or NodeJS.
- Yes, you can access and modify vertices and group them into faces. Default vertex data allows you to set vertex position, normal, color and texture coordinates, although you can set your own customized vertex format if you need to. Take a look at the manual: [Panda3D Manual: Creating and filling a GeomVertexData](https://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Creating_and_filling_a_GeomVertexData)
- Yes, object color can be set using `object.setColor(r,g,b,a)` . More info: [Panda3D Manual: Tinting and Recoloring](http://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Tinting_and_Recoloring)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank's you, it helps, but I think I should clarify what my application is meant to be:
- There should be no window for rendering, because the application is just meant to render a scene directly to an image. It's the image that will be later processed by another application, so we don't need any GUI nor windowing.
- The application is indeed serverside, so there shouldn't be any window.
- I only need to get the vertex and faces from a loaded object from OBJ file, not set them. Are loaded objects an instance of the GeomVertexData?

Comment: Yes you can run Panda3D in the background without any windows, read OBJ files (you will have to convert them to EGG format, I believe) and read its geometry data.

Comment: Ok thank's, I'm reading more and more on the manual and post a summary after, but I still can't find how I can render a single frame in the background!
Can you provide me one last guidance please?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with that, since it is a quite advanced/rare topic. Ask in the Panda3D forums or IRC channel. People in there are very supportive. Good luck!

Comment: So to complete the answer, I've found the solutions to all of my questions in Panda3D 1.8.0: to hide window, use loadPrcFileData("", "window-type offscreen" ) or window-type none if no rendering needed, to render one frame use base.graphicsEngine.renderFrame(), to save as a image file use base.screenshot(), to render just one object, hide all the others using nodePath.hide(), can directly access the vertex and faces using nodePath.getGeom*(), and finally to set color nodePath.setColor() or nodePath.setColorScale() to just tint. More infos: http://www.panda3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=88668

Comment: please add "from panda3d.core import Filename" to the sample code

Comment: Done. Thanks @StepanYakovenko

Answer (score 2):

- You can use a buffer with setOneShot enabled to make it render only a single frame.  You can start Panda3D without a window by setting the "window-type" PRC variable to "none", and then opening an offscreen buffer yourself.  (Note: offscreen buffers without a host window may not be supported universally.)
  If you set "window-type" to "offscreen", `base.win` will actually be a buffer (which may be a bit easier than having to set up your own), after which you can call `base.graphicsEngine.render_frame()` to render a single frame while avoiding the overhead of the task manager.  You have to call it twice because of double-buffering.
- Yes.  Panda3D is used by Disney for some of their MMORPGs.  I do have to add that Panda's high-level networking interfaces are poorly documented.
- You can calculate the transformation from an object to the camera using `nodepath.get_transform(base.cam)`, which is a TransformState object that you may optionally convert into a matrix using `ts.get_mat()`.  This is surprisingly fast, since Panda maintains a composition cache for transformations so that this doesn't have to happen multiple times.  You can get the projection matrix (from view space to clip space) using `lens.get_projection_mat()` or the inverse using `lens.get_projection_mat_inv()`.
  You may also access the individual vertex data using the Geom interfaces, this is described to detail in the Panda3D manual.
- You can use `set_color` to change the base colour of the object (replacing any vertex colours), or you can use `set_color_scale` to tint the objects, ie. applying a colour that is multiplied with the existing colour.  You can also apply a Material object if you use lights and want to use different colours for the diffuse, specular and ambient components.